# Why does Enumerable not have a length attribute in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

At least in Ruby 1.9.3, [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) objects do not have a `length` attribute.  Why is this?

Comment: There is no "Enumerable class".  By "any Enumerable class", do you mean any class for which the `Enumerable` module has been mixed in? Such classes (and others) have a `length` (aka `size`) method.

Comment: There's [`Enumerable#count`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count).

Comment: @ChrisHeald's answer reminded me that, where I said "Such classes have a `length` method, I failed to mention that I was referring to built-in classes, but even of that I am now unsure. Does anyone know of a built-in class that mixes in `Enumerable` that does not have a `length` method?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Range

Comment: @Max, ...or `size`, e.g., [Range#size](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-size). :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland `IO` and `Dir`

Comment: @cremno, thank you.  That's the answer I was looking for.  How silly of me.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks, edited to reflect what I meant.  My brain got a little tangled between inheritance and composition while I was writing that.

Comment: I'm not sure if "Enumerable things*` is much of an improvement over "Emumerable class". :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Max. I think there are quite a few (e.g., `Integer`, `Numerica`, `Proc`, `CSV`, `Matrix`), perhaps a class defining `length` is an exception rather than a rule.

Comment: @CarySwoveland.  I think it is.  Say class `List` includes `Enumerable`, and `list` is an instance of `List`.  Then this holds:  `list.is_a? Enumerable == true`.  Hence, I think it's semantically clean to call `list` an enumerable thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Enumerable has the [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) method, which is usually going to be the intuitive "length" of the enumeration.

But why not call it "length"? Well, because it operates very differently. In Ruby's built-in data structures like `Array` and `Hash`, `length` simply retrieves the pre-computed size of the data structure. It should always return instantly.

For `Enumerable#count`, however, there's no way for it to know what sort of structure it's operating on and thus no quick, clever way to get the size of the enumeration (this is because `Enumerable` is a module, and can be included in any class). The only way for it to get the size of the enumeration is to actually enumerate through it and count as it goes. For infinite enumerations, `count` will (appropriately) loop forever and never return.

Comment: Thanks.  I feel pretty silly for overlooking that.  I'm glad I asked, though.  I wouldn't have realized there was such a difference in behaviour.

Comment: `Enumerator` on the other hand has a `size` method and it works as expected for infinite enumerations: `loop.size #=> Infinity`

Comment: @Stefan, ...and for finite enumerators it need be done lazily. For example, `enum = [1,2,3].to_enum; enum.size #=> nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right, the enumerator has to return its size. But it seems to work for the built-in methods: `[1,2,3].each.size #=> 3`

Answer (score 3):

Enumerables are not guaranteed to have lengths - the only requirement for an object which Enumerable is mixed into is that it responds to `#each`, which causes it to return the next item in the series, and `#<=>` which allows comparison of values provided by the enumerable. Methods like `#sort` will enumerate the entire collection over the course of sorting, but may not know the bounds of the set ahead of time. Consider:

```
class RandomSizeEnumerable
  include Enumerable
  def each
    value = rand 1000
    while value != 500
      yield value
      value = rand 1000
    end
  end

  # Not needed for this example, but included as a part of the Enumerable "interface".
  # You only need this method if #max, #min, or #sort are used on this class.
  def <=>(a, b)
    a <=> b
  end
end
```

This enumerable will be called until the iterator generates the value "500", which will cause it to stop enumerating. The result set is collected and sorted. However, a `#length` method is meaningless in this context, because the length is unknowable until the iterator has been exhausted!

We can call `#length` on the result of things like `#sort`, since they return an array, though:

```
p RandomSizeEnumerable.new.sort.length # 321
p RandomSizeEnumerable.new.sort.length # 227
p RandomSizeEnumerable.new.sort.length # 299
```

Conventionally, `#length` is used when the length is known and can be returned in constant time, whereas `#count` (and sometimes `#size`) tend to be used when the length may not be known ahead of time and needs to be computed by iterating the result set (thus, taking linear time). If you need the size of the result set provided by an Enumerable, try using <s>`.to_a.length`</s> `#count`.

Comment: But there is [`Enumerable#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) which is almost the same as `length`.

Comment: Generally, `#count` is O(n), whereas `#length` is O(1); the documentation and provided sample make this clear, since you would have to iterate the enumerable to discover how many invocations it takes to terminate.

Comment: But `count` is still preferred over `to_a.length`

Comment: Fair point. I think the more complete answer would be "Enumerable doesn't support #length because it can't provide that answer in constant time".

Comment: Good answer. A detail: defining `<=>` is only a requirement if `Enumerable` methods that need it are to be used. There are many `Enumerable` methods (such as `count`) that do not use `<=>`.

Comment: Yup - I just included it because it is an expected part of the Enumerable "interface", even though it's not used in this case.

Comment: ...and other `Enumerable` methods might be used where `<=>` applies to objects of another class (e.g, @Renato Zannon's example of `map`). Consider a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable` isn't really a class, it's a module - a collection of cross-cutting functionality that is used by multiple classes.

For example, `Array`, `Set` and `Hash` all `include` it - you can call any of the `Enumerable` methods on them.

`Enumerable` is notable in that it requires very little of the "host" class. All you need to do is define the `each` method and `include Enumerable`, and you get all those methods for free! Example:

```
class CountUntil
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end

  include Enumerable

  def each
    current = 0
    while current < @number
      yield current
      current += 1
    end
  end
end

# Usage:

CountUntil.new(10).map { |n| n * 5 }
# => [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]
```

As you can see, I never defined `CountUntil#map`, but I got that for free from including `Enumerable`.

To address your question about `length`: not all classes that include `Enumerable` have defined length, even though most do. For example, `Enumerator` can be used to create infinite streams.

Comment: You might want to address the existence of [`Enumerable#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count).